# Using e4 dependency injection to listen to part visibility changes

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

Using Eclipse 4.x, how can I listen to changes to the visibility of parts using dependency injection (or the event broker)?

For activation of parts the following is extremely elegant:

```
@Inject @Optional
void partActivated(@Active MPart part)
```

Its lower-level alternative using events is less elegant but still rather concise:

```
@Inject @Optional
void onActivation(@EventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.ACTIVATE) Event event)
```

But while there exists also a `UIEvents.UILifeCycle.BRINGTOTOP` topic, topics for **visibility** changes (analogous to `IPartLisenter.partVisible` and 
`IPartLisenter.partHidden`) are apparently missing. (`UIEvents.UIElement.TOPIC_VISIBLE` is a red herring here; just because a `MUIElement.isVisible` doesn’t mean it’s visible on screen.)

So, is it possible to use e4’s dependency injection magic to listen to visibility changes (for parts, at least)?

**Note:** I know about the low-level `EPartService.addPartListener(IPartListener)`, but would rather avoid it, as it feels cumbersome and AFAICT would need to be called for every window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of `EPartService` (`org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl`) the part visible events are fired by subscribing to these events:

```
UIEvents.ElementContainer.TOPIC_SELECTEDELEMENT
UIEvents.ApplicationElement.TOPIC_TAGS
```

The part `toBeRendered` flag and the minimized tag setting are then checked.

Given that this is quite complex it seems better to use  `EPartService.addPartListener`.

Comment: Follow-up question: There are two instances of `EPartService` in the context (in an `org.eclipse.e4.legacy.ide.application`, i.e., e4 + compatibility layer): One in the OSGi context for bundle org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench and one in the `WorkbenchContext`. Only the latter supports `addPartListener`; the former (`ApplicationPartServiceImpl`) throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` If I want to get an instance of the `EPartService` from `WorkbenchContext`, how to do this in an add-on (i.e., early during start-up)?

Comment: Can you ask a separate question for this please so I can give an answer that is useful to other people.